# How to inspect an element in IE10 (For Free)

Tags: internet-explorer-10

With chrome, I can right click on any element of the page, and choose "Inspect Element"

How do I get this "kind of working" with IE10 for free ?

Comment: You can press F12 and use the developer tools.

Comment: Yes, my HTML page is more than 2000 lines long, shall I scroll , and click on the little [+] expand hundreds of time before I find the element I want to inspect, or is there any shortcut available to me for this to save me and the business I work for some useless spent monkey time?

Comment: I can send it to OneNote when I right click on it ... ^^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE Developer Tools provides a "click to select" tool - for free.

See [Getting Started with the F12 Developer Tools (IE9/10)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589500(v=vs.85).aspx) and look for "Select element by click":

> The Find menu has only one item, Select element by click. *You can enable this feature from the menu item, by clicking the Select clement by click button Picture of Select Element by Click button or by pressing Ctrl+B.*
>
> *By enabling this feature, you can choose an element on a webpage by clicking the element on the page.* After the element on the webpage is clicked, a border is drawn around the element. If the HTML tab is open, the left pane will scroll to highlight the selected element.
>
> The properties pane (right pane) displays the properties of the selected element, according to the current property type that you have chosen (Style, Trace Styles, Layout, or Attributes). If the HTML tab isn't currently open, using Select element by click selects the element and automatically switches focus back to the HTML tab. Select element by click is only enabled until you click an element.

For IE 11, see [Diagnose and fix layout problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255008(v=vs.85).aspx). The "click to select" still works the same, including the Ctrl+B shortcut, but the developer UI has changed.

Comment: Maybe the guys at Microsoft should hire a usability quality specialist and few decent more testers. Or maybe we should wait end of 2014 before they go below 10% world share market before we can all finally add a page : Sorry, Internet explorer browsers are not supported anymore "..

Answer (score 2):

On IE8 and above you can get the Developer Toolbar by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (or click the pointer) to inspect an element.

Answer (score 0):

press f12 , if that is not working then press ***Crl+Alt+C*** to inspect the page