# How to edit img src of remote website to a location in my local filesystem just for viewing purposes?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

We have a website residing in www.xyz.com and one of the img tags on that website's html has src attribute set to image residing in that server. I want to be able to check how different image would look on the website. I dont currently have access to www.xyz.com and since the website has applet embebed in it I can only use Internet Explorer. Can you tell me what are my options to set image src to file located in my filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the other image on a server somewhere you can edit the src attribute in the inspect pane.

1. right click on the image and choose inspect element
2. edit the src attribute to be the url of the image you want to try out.

This should give you an idea of what it would look like.

Other than that, you can take a screenshot and photoshop the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image is not on the server and I don't have access to that server currently.

Comment: Right but do you have another server that you _do_ have access to?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE do you use ?

I think you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471505/6813732) technique:

- open dev tools by pressing F12
- explore your code, double click on the url
- edit url! ([before](https://up.l3m.in/file/1560948721.png) -> [after](https://up.l3m.in/file/1560949057.png))